# Best way to monitor "connectionState" to identify connected devices in Azure IOTHub periodically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-iot-hub

Our Use Case requires to implement the functionality to know if a device is **Connected/Disconnected** with accuracy<1 minute from WebApp. By implementing heartbeat pattern as advised (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-identity-registry) with a large number of devices it creates enormous volumes of heartbeat messages and it results in generating 99.9% of quota messages just to know when a device goes offline (Disconnected).

Please help me to find the best solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your scenario, you should use an [Operations monitoring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-operations-monitoring) feature of the Azure IoT Hub. This monitoring is closed to the real-time (~8 seconds).

There is a bad news such as the *Operations monitoring* is going to be replaced by **Diagnostics settings** on 10/10/2018, which is not suitable (how it is working today) for a real-time monitoring. It's fine for logging and diagnostics purposes. 
I hope, the MS team will work for this issue to make the Diagnostics settings close to the real-time within the 60 seconds.

**Update:**

The following screen snippet shows an example of the output Diagnostics settings on streaming events captured by Azure Function:

[image: azurefunction]

As you can see, the latency time are minutes and also the events are not in the order when they are happen.

The best replacement of the Operations monitoring (category Connections) should be by Azure Event Grid, in other words making an event-driven.

Comment: Hi @RomanKiss, Thank you for your inputs. I really Appreciate it. I also planned to implement Operation Monitoring feature. But once I saw it is going to be removed from 10/10/2018. then, I was looking for the other Ideas to achieve this functionality. Shall we use Diagnostics settings for monitoring Device Connections? How much accurate it will return the connection state? Or Do I need to find any other way to achieve this? Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Currently the Operations Monitoring feature of the Azure IoT Hub is the best way how for monitoring a device connectivity status to the Azure IoT Hub close to the real-time. It is an event driven solution without any problem for many thousands devices and doesn't require additional cost. In the other side, the Diagnostics settings requires additional cost for EH (~US$22) and what it's worst, it's not for a real-time monitoring. In my case, the latency time is ~360 seconds, what it's absolutely not acceptable for a real-time monitoring.

Comment: It's very difficult to find an event driven replacement for Operations monitoring feature. It must be built-in the Azure IoT Hub. The polling devices or using an heartbeat pattern is fine for very small business model (<100 devices). I hope, that the MS team watching a customer feedback for this issue. I think, the best result should be added to the Azure IoT Hub an event publisher for Event Grid.

Comment: Thank you so much for your inputs. I will implement the Operation Monitoring feature for now. Once, Azure IOTHub Team released the perfect replacement for the Operation Monitoring I will replace it in future. Thanks again for giving a direction and detailed explanations. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Which approach should I implement the Operation Monitoring to monitor Device state? I found Event hub Pooling is given in the MSDN link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-operations-monitoring#how-to-enable-operations-monitoring). Is this approach good for a large number of devices? Please share your thoughts on this. I know, I should ask it as a separate question, but if u answer this question, I will be able to go in the right direction! Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: On the portal/Operations monitoring select a category: "Log events when a device connects ..." for Verbose and Save it. That's all. For consuming those events, I do recommend to use an Azure EventHubTrigger Function. Your business needs can be implemented within this function.

Comment: I'll add my feedback, too, in case MS ever checks this: Azure Diagnostics is not a workable replacement for Ops Monitoring.  With Ops Monitoring, we're able to get immediately feedback when a device connects and disconnects, without wasting additional bandwidth sending heartbeats manually.  I'm hoping Azure Diagnostics eventually reaches this level, but it isn't there yet.